# DynamoDB - What happens when I delete a object in a GSI? Does it "Cascade" to the main table?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Let's say in my main table I have objects that have the following pattern :

```
Partition Key = user_user@email.com
Range Key = project_001
Role = owner
```

It's a simple object that says what is the role if a specific user in a specific project.

But then I want to get all user roles in a project, so I made a GSI that inverts the key orders by using `Range Key Begins With "user_"`

```
Partition Key = project_001
Range Key = user_user@email.com
Role = owner
```

But what happens when I delete a object in this GSI? Will it delete the respective object it replicated from the main table? Or do I need to manually keep them synchronized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delete via a GSI.

[DeleteItem()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html) only accepts the table name.

That will cascade down to the GSI.